# Copy Structure with 2D Array Pointer in C++ - Pointer Arithmetic

Tags: c++11

The following code doesnt allow the pointer to be accessed as a 2D Array with the notation i have used in class. Am i missing something here ? Src and Dst are allocated memory outside this func.

```
/* Map is a 2 Dimensional Array width = x and height = y */
/* if value of loc in src is 32 do not copy to dest */
struct Map {
   int *loc;
   int x; /
   int y;
}

/* Copy Map from Source to Dest */ 
void copyMap(Map *src, Map *dst)
{
    for (int i=0 ; i < src->x; x++)
    {
        for (int j=0 ; j < src->y; y++)
        {
            // loc is 32 skip save to dest 
            if (src->loc[i][j] != 32)
            {
              dest->loc[i][j] = src->loc[i][j]; // ==> Cant i access the pointer as 2D Array
            }

            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `loc` looks like a one-dimensional array to me. You may be looking for something like `for (int i = 0; i < src->x*src->y; ++i) { dest->loc[i] = src=>loc[i]; }`  (checking for 32 is left as an exercise for the reader).

Comment: Thanks @IgorTandetnik -> Let me try that out. Its a 2 Dimensional Array but i see what you meant with the "src->x*src->y". i may still have to access it as 2D as i may be required to copy the data with some offset on dest x and y. Then 1D notation wont help. I should maybe modify the question above.

Comment: `loc[i*y+j]` or `loc[i+x*j]` should work for "2D" access, depending on whether you chose row-major or column-major order.